# position of logo and page border for printing by pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I wrote this code. I need a function that put my logo in middle of first line. And how do I add a border to my page?

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_5,QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")),self.Delete)
def Delete(self):
    self.printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
    self.printer.setPageSize(self.printer.A4)
    self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    self.cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor()
    self.cursor = self.text.textCursor()
    self.image = QtGui.QTextImageFormat()
    self.image.setName("leaf.jpg")
    self.cursor.insertImage(self.image)      
    pdialog = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(self.printer)
    pdialog.paintRequested.connect(self.text.print_)
    pdialog.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this code before `self.image`

```
self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```